# An infinite compact set which allows no boundedness and analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis, compactness, analyticity

I need an example of an infinite compact set $K$ in $\mathbb {C}$ such that there does not exist any non-constant function which is both bounded and analytic on $\mathbb{C} - K$.

First, any hints would be appreciated...

Comment: Hint: Riemann's removable singularity theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer Isn't Riemann's theorem on isolated singularities (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) ? I'm not sure how that helps here.

Comment: @PVAL One needs to find some infinite compact $K$ such that every bounded holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$ is constant. If one can arrange it so that all points of $K$ become removable singularities ...